# Wordpress Multiple sub installations - htaccess / index.php

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two wordpress installations - each in their own directory - on my one main domain. like `mydomain.com/site1` and `mydomain.com/site2`

By default when visiting `mydomain.com` it redirects to `mydomain.com/site1`

I am unsure where this redirect is coming from. There is no .htaccess file in the root of the main domain `mydomain.com` nor any Index.php file in the root of the main domain.

I have also checked both .htaccess files of each directory installation `mydomain.com/site1` and `mydomain.com/site2` and do not seem to find what is causing the main domain `mydomain.com` to redirect to `mydomain.com/site1`

***My main goal is to change the main domain `mydomain.com` to redirect to `mydomain.com/site2` by default***

The contents of each .htaccess are as follows:

**Site 1 .htaccess**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site1/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /site1/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
# BEGIN wtfdivi
# END wtfdivi
```

**Site 2 .htaccess**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site2/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /site2/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
# BEGIN wtfdivi
# END wtfdivi
```

**The contents of both directories Index.php (`mydomain.com/site1` and `mydomain.com/site2` )are identical as follows**

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

Comment: is your site is live? Did you set those url from settings?

Comment: @Md.AbuZaman - Yes both sites are live, and the url is set in WP settings on each to `mydomain.com/site1`  and `mydomain.com/site2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, Now you can set your redirect url from phpmyadmin.

1. Go to your database and find the `wp_options` table.
2. Now edit the `siteurl` column and set your domain url here you want to reditect.
3. Then edit the 2nd column `home` for your home page and set the same url.

Please clear the cache or press Ctrl+Shift+R or check it from the new incoming window.

Comment: Do I edit the database for mydomain.com/site1 or mydomain.com/site2

Comment: you wrote that you want `mydomain.com to redirect to mydomain.com/site2 by default` so go to `mydomain.com/site1` and set `mydomain.com/site2`

Comment: Thank you.  I see 'siteurl' but do not have the column 'home'

Comment: first column is `siteurl` and 2nd column is `home`.

Comment: If your problem is solved please mark it as correct answers.

Comment: Apologies I am not finding the 'home' column

Comment: Can you please tell me the name of  your 2nd column?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182079/discussion-between-user2502658-and-md-abu-zaman).

Comment: Please click your logo and home menu for checking that your site is working fine.